# using ant design components with angular

Tags: angular, antd, ant-design-pro, ng-zorro-antd

I am facing a strange and confusing problem. 
Working on an angular 8 project and using ant design components https://ant.design/.
What I need to do is one login page and one layout which after successful login attempt user will redirect to that.
login and layout was organized as angular modular structure.

User can see the login page as expected but default module which is real application does not seems as should be.

I have uploaded my project to github.

https://github.com/azizkazdal/AngularAntDesginTemplate

So I need some advise please.
And I also attached the screen shot

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to move `app.component.css` content to `layout.component.css`, and modify `app.component.css` content as follows:

```css
:host {
  width: 100%;
}
```

---

[image]